# Visual Studio 2022 SQL Compare giving The target principal name is incorrect error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2022

We have a SQL project in Visual Studio and recently moved from VS2019 to VS2022.  In 2019 our SCMP compare works fine but in 2022 we get the error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
> error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.) (Microsoft SQL
> Server, Error: -2146893022)

We use integrated security for database security.

Comment: Sounds like the SPN is not set up correctly. If you look at the SQL Server error log you might see something about a Service Principal Name in the logs shortly after startup

Comment: Have opened Control Panel > User Accounts > Credentials Manager yet to check your saved Windows Credentials and saved Generic Credentials? I expect you have something saved there for VS2019 that needs to be setup for VS2022 as well.

Comment: I don't see anything in the Credential Manager for VIsual Studio 2019.

Comment: I've seen this error when there are problems with certificates: [how-to-fix-the-target-principal-name-is-incorrect-error-with-microsoft-data-sq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527434/how-to-fix-the-target-principal-name-is-incorrect-error-with-microsoft-data-sq)

Comment: For some reason when using the UI, it wouldn't save my advanced settings.  I edited the file directly to change the connection string to TrustCertificate and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason when using the UI, it wouldn't save my advanced settings. I edited the file directly to change the connection string to TrustCertificate and it works now